# antipode temperature equation

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: 
For any point $x$ on the sphere, the antipode, $-x$, is the point which is exactly on the other side.

$E =$ surface of the sphere.

Let $T : E \to R$ be a continuous function where $T(x)$ represents the temperature at the point $x.$ Prove that there exists a point $x$ on the equator such that $T(x) = T(-x).$

My idea: Maybe we can assume there doesn't exist such point $x$ and show that this results in that $T$ is not a continuous function anymore, which is a contradiction!

I'm not sure how to show this though.

Comment: Try to show that $T-S$, where $S(x)=T(-x)$, has a zero, using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Is this correct? I pick nonzero x and let this x as a. then f(a) = T(a) - T(-a), and f(-a) = T(-a)-T(a). Then f(a)= -f(-a). So if they are o, then there exists T(a) = T(-a) and if they are not 0, one of them is positive and one of them is negative. Hence, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists b ∈ E such that f(b) = 0 which means T(b) = t(-b). Is this right?

Comment: That's it. Just make sure you point out that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** consider the function 
$$
\begin{align}
f:E&\to \mathbb R\\
x&\mapsto T(x)-T(-x)
\end{align}
$$
Now, trying the intermediate value theorem at the correct points should give you a proof.

Comment: Actually, if you want this proof in video form, you might like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLMrtJn-MOYmdbPmMYmArKa-LPIQmeicJB&v=PVcnGNToaCg&feature=player_detailpage&t=120

Comment: Is this correct? I pick nonzero x and let this x as a. then f(a) = T(a) - T(-a), and f(-a) = T(-a)-T(a). Then f(a)= -f(-a). So if they are o, then there exists T(a) = T(-a) and if they are not 0, one of them is positive and one of them is negative. Hence, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists b ∈ E such that f(b) = 0 which means T(b) = t(-b). Is this right?

Comment: That's exactly how it's done. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the result that a continuous bijection between a compact space and a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. Now, you can consider a map T:$S^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ as a map from $S^2$ onto $T(S^2)$. If this map were an injection, then it would be an embedding of the compact space $S^2$ into the Hausdorff space $\mathbb R$ (or, more accurately, the (Hausdorff) subspace $T(S^2)$ , which is not possible for many reasons --not even $S^1$ can be embedded into $\mathbb R$

See:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem